# JQuery select element in shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

HTML code:

```
<textarea name="remark" rows="4" cols="30">
  #shadow-root (user-agent)
  <div id="inner-editor">
    "this is text in textarea"
  </div>
</textarea>
```

I am trying select element DIV with `id="inner-editor"` with this JQuery:

`var el = $("[name='remark']").children();`

but the `var el` is empty. If I try this:

`$("[name='remark']").text();`

It is also empty output.

`#shadow-root (user-agent)` is something like template (I dont know exactle what it is) and isn't display in textarea

Is it possible select this element DIV in textarea element?

Comment: How is that even Shadow DOM …?

Comment: Downvoted because it's not shadow DOM

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me to select an element within Shadow root. I have converted it to your scenario.

```
let textArea = $("textarea[name='remark']"); 
let sr = $(textArea)[0].shadowRoot; 
console.log($(sr).find('.#inner-editor'));
```

Hope this may help somebody.

Answer (score 5):

I dont really get your example, but i guess you are hiding `<div id="inner-editor">`in the Shadow Root of the `<textarea name="remark" rows="4" cols="30">`.

You need to select the `<textarea name="remark" rows="4" cols="30">` and there you can access the Shadow Root of the element via the `shadowRoot` javascript property.

Full example:

```
var el = $("[name='remark']").shadowRoot.getElementById("inner-editor");
```

**Edit:**
With Jquery, according to your question, you need to pass the shadowRoot to Jquery. It  should work with Jquery as well:

```
var sr = $("[name='remark']").shadowRoot;
var el = $(sr).find("#inner-editor");
```

Comment: for me shadow root property returns undefined

Comment: After testing I found that putting this works:  var sr = $("[name='remark']")[0].shadowRoot;

Answer (score -2):

It works after copied your html and js code. please check at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2gjzcyh/2/)

Make sure including jquery.min.js

```
<textarea name="remark" rows="4" cols="30"> #shadow-root (user-agent) <div id="inner-editor"> "this is text in textarea" </div> </textarea>
alert($("[name='remark']").text());

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>      
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
alert($("[name='remark']").text());
});
//]]>      
</script>  

</head>
<body>
  <textarea name="remark" rows="4" cols="30"> #shadow-root (user-agent) <div id="inner-editor"> "this is text in textarea" </div> </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in fiddle is `#shadow-root (user-agent)` -> only text, on webside is a something like "template" and JQUERY selectors catn't select nothing from this `#shadow-root (user-agent)` -> include: `<div id="inner-editor"></div>`

Comment: You are writing #shadow-root in html, while the question asks the #shadow-root created automatically by the browser