# Shadowroot : Attaching jquery event handlers to multiple elements under shadowRoot

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shadow-dom

So I'm using a jQuery plugin under shadowRoot in my app. The HTML is as follows

```
#shadow-root
<div id="container">
   <div class="display-item">Item 1</div>
   <div class="display-item">Item 2</div>
   <div class="display-item">Item 3</div>
   <div class="display-item">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

I want to attach event listeners to the divs with class = "display-item" for events like mousedown,mousedown,focus. I tried the following:

```
let root = document.getElementById(divID).shadowRoot;
$(root).on('mousedown', '#container div.display-item', function(event) {
//function 
});
```

But this doesn't work. How could I make this work?

**EDIT :**

I also tried this approach, something like $('#container .display-item'), but it wouldn't work since it's looking for those elements under document I believe and it wouldn't find them since they're under the shadow DOM,so I have to use the root as pivot. Is there an equivalent of jquery 'find' method where I can query like multiple elements with the same class, using the shadow root as pivot? That way, I can attach event listeners to the individual elements explicitly.

Comment: Guess that the [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is wrong.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, I tried this approach, something like ```$('#container .display-item')```, but it wouldn't work since it's looking for those elements under document I believe and it wouldn't find them since they're under the shadow DOM,so I have to use the root as pivot. Is there an equivalent of jquery 'find' method where I can query like multiple elements with the same class, using the shadow root as pivot? That way, I can attach event listeners to the individual elements explicitly.

Comment: Does your `document.getElementById(divID).shadowRoot;` expression work? If so, what type of object is `root`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888, the expression works. root is a shadow-root object. Logging it in the console gives me this: ```shadow-root (open)```

Comment: Do the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29216899/3478010) shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

In the ideal world Web Components should **care** about the "outside" world,
and most of all the Outside should not be **dependent** on Web Components inner
world.

- That means the Component should take care of attaching listeners.
- Since you are in control what the Component does, there is no need for `addEventListener` (allowing for multiple same listeners)

```js
customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({mode: "open"})
      .innerHTML = `<div id="container">
   <div class="display-item">Item 1</div>
   <div class="display-item">Item 2</div>
   <div class="display-item">Item 3</div>
   <div class="display-item">Item 4</div>
</div>`;
  }
  listen() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.display-item').forEach(div => {
      div.onclick = (evt) => {
        document.body.append(div.innerText);
      }
    });
    this.listen = () => console.warn("ran attach listener once");
  }
})
```

```html
<my-component id=COMP></my-component>

<script>
  window.onload=()=>{
    document.querySelector("#COMP").listen();
  }
</script>
```

Note: IE9 was the last browser to implement JS queryselectors... **in 2011**

If you are only using jQuery for its `$()`, you have burdened your clients with a not required 80KB+ download for the past 11 years.

If you really want to **touch** the Inside World

```
 document.querySelector("#COMP").shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.display-item').forEach
```

does the trick, but breaks when there are more shadowRoots in between.

And in my world I don't **tell** Components what to do,
I make Components **listen**:

```
      window.onload=()=>{
        document.dispatchEvent("LISTEN");
      }
```