# Remap all jQuery Selectors to shadowRoot

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, shadow-dom

Due to specifications by a customer we are trying to completely replace an iframe element by a a web component with shadow DOM.

The plan is, that the website, which should be embeded, is fetched via ajax and afterwards placed in a shadow dom inside a web component.

Basically this works as intended. The fetched HTML can be inserted into a shadow DOW, located in a custom web component. CSS styles also behave like in an iframe (encapsulated).

But we got major problems with the JavaScript, which is part of the child page. Because the fetched HTML is written into the shadow DOM, embedded JavaScript is not executed.

This can be solved by reading the  tags from the fetched HTML and placing them via .appendChild into the shadow DOM.

With this it is manageable to load external javascript files and execute direct javascript code in the shadow dom.

BUT, and now leading to the problem:

All jQuery DOM selectors from the embedded site of course do not work. They are natively searching in the DOM of the parent page, not in the DOM of the shadow.

Is there a good way to map all of those selectors to the shadow dom?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery select element in shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216899/jquery-select-element-in-shadow-dom)

Comment: Thanks for the response! This answer describes, how a selector can be used to access elements of the shadow root. I know how to do that. The question is, if there is a way to achive this for a whole JavaScript file?

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine $ inside your web component:

```
connectedCallback () { 
  const elem = this
  const $ = (e, t) => window.jQuery(e, elem.shadowRoot);
  window.jQuery.extend($, window.jQuery);
```

Note that this is quite hacky and may not cover all cases